# Qt signals slots, cast type in new notation

Tags: c++, qt

Given the following two:

```
connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(activated(QString)), ps, SLOT(requestPlotsAvailable(QString)));
connect(ui->comboBox, &QComboBox::activated, ps, &PlotSystem::requestPlotsAvailable);
```

The first uses the old notation, which works. The second uses the new notation and gives the error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'PlotSystemGui::connect(QComboBox*&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

How to avoid the error using the new notation?

Comment: @hyde, sorry, it was a typo.

Answer (score 8):

This should work

```
connect(ui->comboBox, 
        static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(const QString &)>(&QComboBox::activated),
        ps,
        &PlotSystem::requestPlotsAvailable);
```

Qt 5.7 introduces [`qOverload` (or QOverload for C++11)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload) for convenience/readability:

```
connect(ui->comboBox, 
        qOverload<const QString &>(&QComboBox::activated),
        ps,
        &PlotSystem::requestPlotsAvailable);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874489/disambiguate-overloaded-member-function-pointer-being-passed-as-template-paramet) question about pointers to overloaded functions

Comment: It returns another error: no matches converting function 'activated' to type 'void (class QComboBox::*)(class QString)'

Comment: yep, because it should be `const QString &` instead of `QString`.  (edited answer)

Comment: The problem is, as described in the first message, that the compiler cannot resolve which of the overloaded functions to take.  So `static_cast` needed to tell explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanaton, I guess I understand the problem.

Comment: Let's say I want to link an int signal with a QString slot, Is it possible to link diferent types?

Comment: I assume it will work if an implicit conversion sequence exists between types.  Thus connecting an `int` signal to a `double` slot will work, but not to the `QString` slot since there is no implicit conversion.